# php files automatically add line break and space into each line?

Tags: php

I'm working on a wordpress site and I'm editing the function.php. The problem is whenever I made some changes to it and upload back to the server it automatically add an empty line to it.

Original php:

```
function registerWidget() {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'          => 'FooterMessage',
    'id'            => 'footer-message',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="FooterMessage">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
));
```

Few days after and downloaded back from the server:

```
function registerWidget() {

register_sidebar(array(

    'name'          => 'FooterMessage',

    'id'            => 'footer-message',

    'before_widget' => '<div class="FooterMessage">',

    'after_widget'  => '</div>',

));
```

Is there a way to prevent this and is there any online tool that allow me to remove all these excessive empty lines without doing it manually?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @meh I'm using dreamweaver

Comment: find the `find and replace` tool in dreamweaver or you can do it by notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **Notepad++** press `CTRL + h`

Choose `Regular Expression` in Search Mode.

Find what: `\r\n\r\n`

Replace With: `\r\n`

Then click on `Replace All`

---

You can use any tools that has Find&Replace by regex.